# Turing machine that recognizes the language $\{a^{n}b^{2n}c^{3n}|\ n\ge0\}$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability

I'm pretty sure that the Turing machine state diagram I drew accepts all strings in the language $\{a^{n}b^{2n}c^{3n}|\ n\ge0\}$, but how do you verify this? Likewise, how do you verify that this machine rejects any string not in the given language?

[image: Turing machine diagram drawin in JFLAP]

Comment: Are you familiar with program verification? with loop invariants?  with proof by induction?

Comment: Proof by induction, yes. I am not familiar with program verification or loop invariants.

Comment: I'd suggest you start by learning about loop invariants and see if you can prove your Turing machine correct by identifying appropriate invariants.  It might get tedious.

Comment: We typically don't formally prove that Turing machines work correctly, since it's very tedious. Indeed, we typically don't even describe them formally, because even that is quite tedious.

Answer (score -1):

you should test it with different combinations of a,b and c. This is the only method I know till now to validate the turing machine you've constructed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).